# while loop condition in singly linkedlist

Tags: loops, while-loop, singly-linked-list

Was solving cycle detection in a Singly linkedlist and came across a problem which I can't seem to understand in the While Loop

I've attached an image, the one in green boxes gave me the correct output

While the ones in red boxes gave me the wrong output

Any explanation  on the difference between these 2? As I couldn't seem to find the difference between them other than their ordering but I have set an AND statement so I supposed they should work regardless of their ordering but that doesn't seem to be the case which I have encountered

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **AND** condition first condition will be checked first and if that is False, it won't go to the second one and return from there.

Here, while in first one which is

`oneUp.next != null`

It won't be able to access next of **oneUp** in the case when the value of **oneUp** is null.
So we need to verify the value of **OneUp** that it should not be null.

If it is null, it won't go and check for the next condition.

So that `oneUp != null`  has to be checked first.